# Oracle concurrent programming execution methods

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I created a package and a stored procedure under it to test a concurrent program.  When I run it as an Oracle report executable method it works fine.  But when I change it to PL/SQL stored procedure then it produces an error.

```
Cause: FDPSTP failed due to ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'POPULATE_REPORT_STG_TBL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

It's working properly in the Oracle report method.